# An error occurred while installing the react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

This is an error that occurred while I was installing the react app:

npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-08T11_06_24_191Z-debug.log
Установка [ 'create-react-app@latest' ] завершилась с кодом ошибки 1

how can i fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems some sort of network certificate issue.

You can try this command:

`npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

and then try installing again your `react-app`.

Comment: this code did not help